# Bundle stencil.js into single file

Tags: javascript, web-component, stenciljs

I'm trying to use a stencil web-component in a system that requires a single js file. To be more precise, this is because the target system will take all javascript files and bundle them regardless. When i add the ES6 javascript files, this throws errors, which i think is because they are supposed to be lazy-loaded.

How can i generate a single bundle.js file, that can simply be added using the script tag?

Comment: How did you add the javascript files, and what error did you get?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Custom Elements Bundle](https://stenciljs.com/docs/custom-elements) output target.

> The dist-custom-elements-bundle output target is used to generate custom elements as a single bundle.

To use this file without a bundler you also need to disable the `externalRuntime` config:

```
export const config: Config = {
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist-custom-elements-bundle',
      externalRuntime: false,
    },
    // ...
};
```

Note that you will still need to register (or "define") your components (and  set the asset path if applicable) after you include the script.

Comment: Right. I tried to use the javascript in the custom-elements folder, but this would just return errors. I will give it a try after disabling externalRuntime.

Comment: Yes, without `externalRuntime: false` it will throw import errors since it's trying to import the Stencil runtime (meant for use with a bundler and with `@stencil/core` installed). This tells the compiler to include the runtime as well.

Comment: I didn't get around to try this yet, but as i remember, it was trying to import stencil/core from the node modules, so this sounds like it will work.
Thanks for help :)

Answer (score -2):

Your question will get only a handful of views here on StackOverflow,
because it is specific to an OpenSource tool.

OpenSource tools (nearly) always have a GitHub repo.

You can file issues there: **https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues**

or the Slack channel: **https://stencil-worldwide.herokuapp.com/**

---

If you are learning Web Components, consider learning the core JavaScript technology first.

If you learn a Tool (like Stencil) *before* learning the Technology you will forever be asking questions you could have solved yourself... IMHO

If you use core Web Components technology you will not have any bundling issues.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer actually helps since the question is about the capabilities (and configurability) of a tool. And I'd say SO is a better platform for those types of questions than GitHub issues. Just mentioning it because it's a new contributer..

Comment: The [StencilJS Repo Issue List](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues) is one of the best around.

Comment: Yeah, they recently hired new people which helped. But for questions I would recommend the very active [Slack channel](https://stencil-worldwide.herokuapp.com/). I added it to the [Stencil tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stenciljs/info) but that change has to be peer reviewed before it's live.